# JPA direction of entity relationships

Tags: java, jpa

I am new to JPA and am having some difficulty understanding the "Direction in Entity Relationships" concepts as described here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/persistence-intro001.htm#BNBQI

Is uni- or bidirectionality something that you choose when designing your entities or is it given by the database schema? Like in the order application (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/persistence-basicexamples001.htm), could you for example design it so that the `lineitem` knows about which orders it belongs to, but an `order` wouldn't know which lineitems it has?

Answer (score 2):

You decide whether a relationship is uni-directional or bi-directional by the fields and annotations you include on the entities.

**Uni-directional**

```
@Entity
public class Parent(){

    @OneToMany
    private List<Child> children;
}

@Entity
public class Child(){

}
```

**Bi-directional**

```
@Entity
public class Parent(){

    @OneToMany
    private List<Child> children;
}

@Entity
public class Child(){

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private Parent parent;
}
```

As you can see the **uni-directional** relationship does not allow the child to access the parent, while the **bi-directional** does allow parent access.  This link is created by adding an annotated field to the child of the parent's type and is completely optional.  It boils down to a design decision.

Of course the database must support the relationship, meaning the proper primary/foreign keys are established to link the tables, but nothing **special** is required in your database.

One important concept to be aware of when modeling these relationships is the **owning** entity.  I have written this [article](http://blog-tothought.rhcloud.com/post/5) about the topic which may be helpful.

Comment: And I am free to decide this myself? I don't have to implement it a certain way based on what the database schema looks like?

Answer (score 0):

That depend upon your requirement

```
Unidirectional

@Entity
@AutoProperty
public class OneToOneUnidirectionalA implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @OneToOne
    private OneToOneUnidirectionalB b;

    private String s;

    // Setters, Getters, Constructors, Pojomatic...

}


@Entity
@AutoProperty
public class OneToOneUnidirectionalB implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    // No reference to OneToOneUnidirectionalA
    // since this is a unidirectional relationship

    private String s;

    // Setters, Getters, Constructors, Pojomatic...

}
```

Bidirectional
A owns the relationship. We need to avoid Pojomatic circular reference issues too:

```
@Entity
@AutoProperty
public class OneToOneBidirectionalA implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Property(policy=PojomaticPolicy.NONE)
    @OneToOne
    private OneToOneBidirectionalB b;

    // Setters, Getters, Constructors, Pojomatic...

}



@Entity
@AutoProperty
public class OneToOneBidirectionalB implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Property(policy=PojomaticPolicy.NONE)
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="b")
    private OneToOneBidirectionalA a;

    // Setters, Getters, Constructors, Pojomatic...

}
```